# jQuery - Hide el with attribute stored in array

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure my title makes sense because I've confused myself, sorry!

So I have an array of ID's.  These are also used as rel attributes on my elements.

IF my element has an ID that's stored in my array, hide it.

This is what I've tried:

```
(function ($) {
        var $hotspot = $('.hotspot'),
            hidePrdArr = ['1461162215', '1461162123'],
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < $hotspot.length; i += 1) {
            $('.hotspot[rel="' + hidePrdArr.eq(i) + '"]').hide()
        }
    }(jQuery));
```

It works when there's only 1 ID in the array, but when I add the next it stops.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the answer about eq(), your for loop is iterating through the list of .hotspot elements found but you're using that index  for looking up on hidePrdArr. I think you should be iterating through hidePrdArr instead.

Try:

```
(function ($) {
    var $hotspot = $('.hotspot'),
        hidePrdArr = ['1461162215', '1461162123'],
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < hidePrdArr.length; i += 1) {
        $('.hotspot[rel="' + hidePrdArr[i] + '"]').hide()
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

`eq()` is not an array method.

Instead of this:

```
$('.hotspot[rel="' + hidePrdArr.eq(i) + '"]').hide()
```

… index directly into the array using square brackets like this:

```
$('.hotspot[rel="' + hidePrdArr[i] + '"]').hide()
```

```js
var $hotspot = $('.hotspot'),
    hidePrdArr = ['1461162215', '1461162123'],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < $hotspot.length; i += 1) {
  $('.hotspot[rel="' + hidePrdArr[i] + '"]').hide()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hotspot" rel="1461162215">1461162215</div>
<div class="hotspot" rel="4893729847">4893729847</div>
<div class="hotspot" rel="9087423874">9087423874</div>
<div class="hotspot" rel="1461162123">1461162123</div>
```